# Creat a mask from specific value of a Mat (in EMGU)

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

In OpenCv C++ you can do:

```
int nbrLabel = connectedComponentsWithStats(img, labelsMat, stats, centroids);
int selectedLabel = 4;
Mat mask = (labelsMat == selectedLabel);
```

`mask` will be the size of `img` and store if each pixel is equal to `selectedLabel` or not.

Emgu doesn't have a `==` operator for Mat.
What would be the best solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found was to use InRange from the `Image<>` class with the same `lower`and `higher` value:

```
int nbrLabel = CvInvoke.ConnectedComponentsWithStats(img, labelsMat, stats, centroids);
Image<Gray, byte> labelsImg = labelsMat.ToImage<Gray, byte>();
int selectedLabel = 4;
Mat mask = labelsImg.InRange(new Gray(selectedLabel), new Gray(selectedLabel)).Mat
```